# Can't connect to MySQL from django website with Python 2.7, but is ok with Python 2.5

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python

When I use Python 2.7 to connect to MySQL I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 48, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 249, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "C:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\validation.py", line 102, in get_validation_errors
    connection.validation.validate_field(e, opts, f)
  File "C:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\validation.py", line 14, in validate_field
    db_version = self.connection.get_server_version()
  File "C:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 313, in get_server_version
    self.cursor()
  File "C:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 75, in cursor
    cursor = self._cursor()
  File "C:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 297, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)")
```

The same code/mysql instance works fine when I use Python 2.5 with MySQLdb driver.
How can I fix it?
Thanks!

**UPD**: I use MySQL-python-1.2.4.win-amd64-py2.7 with Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: Is mysqldb a requirement for Python2.7.  I wonder if there is a different MySQLdb for 2.7 that you need which you currently have for Python 2.5

Comment: Are you sure that you have installed the correct MySQL-python connector for python2.7?

Comment: @ScotchAndSoda I have Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 and I installed MySQL-python-1.2.4.win-amd64-py2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is strange, but looks like it is solved.

I tried this precompiled driver: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python and it fails.

After it I tried this one: http://www.codegood.com/archives/129 and it is ok.